# Can't access $rootScope Variable although it's there

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

When I do this in Chrome with AngularJS:

```
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function($injector, $location){
        var $state = $injector.get("$state");
        var $rootScope = $injector.get("$rootScope");

        console.log($rootScope);
        console.log($rootScope.isAuthenticated);
    }
```

Then in the console I get

[image]

Open the first line and I see the "isAuthenticated" is set (either false or true). As expected.

But the second line gives me an `undefined`. WTF?

#### Why is this and how to access this property?

Comment: It might be the case that whatever populates isAuthenticated runs between the time that your code in the example runs and the time you expand the object in Chrome. Try put a breakpoint in between the two lines then looking in $rootScope while it's paused.

Comment: How is `$rootScope.isAuthenticated` set?

Comment: It is set in app.run... inside the $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart'...

Comment: @Macha: do you know of any way to test this? I thought when I do a console.log that this is a snapshot and not changed afterwords, am I mistaken?

Comment: Change the code to:

`console.log($rootScope); debugger;`

This will freeze the execution of further code until you hit run in your dev tools again.

console.log does take a snapshot, but only a shallow one and only at the time you first expand the object (This may not be the same in every browser)

Comment: Awesome! How in the world do you know this? You want to write an answer to this or should I do it?

Comment: I left it as a comment, because I'm not sure how you can get at your isAuthenticated property you originally asked about, I just knew why the method you tried didn't work :)

Comment: Thank you, actually that answered my question, probably I didn't write the title clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thanks to @Macha I got the answer.

By the time I expand the object in Chrome my code populates the object. The code above runs in `app.config`. Later the isAuthenticated gets set in `app.run`.

This means that both lines are snapshots but when I expand the object, Chrome gets the current content - which explains the difference between the two lines.

You can see this by adding `debugger;` like this:

```
console.log($rootScope); debugger;
```

And then looking into the object while the code is on pause. This almost cost some of my hairs.